# Error de routing en Manage de Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

El urlque intenta

```
http://localhost:49261/Manage/DeleteRole/88300fce-a86f-463f-ab5b-8a5f61b9b210
```

No se encuentra la vista 'Administrador' ni su vista maestra o no hay un motor de búsqueda que admita las ubicaciones de búsqueda. Se buscó en las siguientes ubicaciones:

```
~/Views/Manage/Administrador.aspx
~/Views/Manage/Administrador.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Administrador.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Administrador.ascx
~/Views/Manage/Administrador.cshtml
~/Views/Manage/Administrador.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Administrador.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Administrador.vbhtml
```

Sale esto cuando trato de ir de una vista get a una post:

```
// GET:
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteRole(string id)
        {
            string nombre = string.Empty;

            if (id == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }

            var elRol = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

            if (elRol != null)
            {
                nombre = elRol.Name;
            }
            return View(nombre);
        }         

        // POST:
        [HttpPost]        
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteRole(string id, FormCollection form)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                var elRol = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
                //var elRol = await RoleManager.FindByNameAsync(id);

                if (elRol != null)
                {
                    IdentityResult roleRuslt = RoleManager.DeleteAsync(elRol).Result;
                    if (roleRuslt.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Roles");
                    }
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```

La vista:

```
@model PruebaHG.Models.RoleViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DeleteRole";
}

<h2>DeleteRole</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>RoleViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteRole", "Manage", FormMethod.Post)) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Roles")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Hice otras cosas en el controlador Manage de Identity y me funcionaron bien. Ahora agrego las acciones para borrar y el routing no funciona, incluso adicioné la acción y el controlador en BeginForm. Escogo el rol para borrar, le doy al botón y saca el error.

Intenta ir a Manage/Administrador en lugar de Manage/DeleteRole y no entiendo por qué

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +198
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) +152
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +126
```

Así queda el código con la respuesta de Salvador

```
 // GET:
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteRole(string id)
        {
            string nombre = string.Empty;

            if (id == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }

            var elRol = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

            if (elRol != null)
            {
                nombre = elRol.Name;
            }

            //Creas el ViewModel que espera la vista..
            RoleViewModel vm = new RoleViewModel();
            //Le seteas las propiedades
            vm.Name = nombre;
            //Retornas el ViewModel.
            return View(vm);
        }         

        // POST:
        [HttpPost]        
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteRoleAction(string nombre)
        {
            if (nombre != null)
            {
                var elRol = await RoleManager.FindByNameAsync(nombre);                

                if (elRol != null)
                {
                    IdentityResult roleRsult = RoleManager.DeleteAsync(elRol).Result;
                    if (roleRsult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Roles");
                    }
                }
            }

            return View("Error");
        }
```

Comment: Por que queres ir de una acción GET a una acción POST?

Comment: Para borrar un rol

Comment: Pero no es necesario.. desde el formulario deberías llegar ir directamente con el verbo post, si el id llega como parámetro, que recibirías en el FormCollection?

Comment: A todo esto, el error se produce antes de llegar al formulario cierto?

Comment: Nada. Eso lo saqué de un tutorial y estoy tratando de adaptarlo. ¿Lo quito?

Comment: Selecciono el rol, le doy al botón y ahí sale el error @JuanSalvadorPortugal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema tiene mucho sentido!

Se da debido a que estas haciendo utilizando la sobrecarga incorrecta de [`View()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_View_System_String_), en tu caso, estas usando [`View(string viewName)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_View_System_String_), donde el parámetro es, justamente el nombre de la vista, por lo cual, asumiendo (con total seguridad) le estas pasando la palabra `Administrador` que estas obteniendo en esta línea `nombre = elRol.Name`

La sobrecarga que deberías usar es [`View(Object)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_View_System_Object_).

Donde el `Object` que pasarás de parámetro debe ser del tipo que esta tipando tu vista, en tu ejemplo es `PruebaHG.Models.RoleViewModel`

Por ende, lo que debes hacer es instanciar un objeto de tipo `RoleViewModel`, asignarle las propiedades de tu interes, y, a este sí lo pasarás como parámetro de `View()`

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteRole(string id)
{
    string nombre = string.Empty;

    if (id == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    var elRol = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

    if (elRol != null)
    {
        nombre = elRol.Name;
    }
    //Creas el ViewModel que espera la vista..
    RoleViewModel vm = new RoleViewModel();
    //Le seteas las propiedades
    vm.Name = nombre;
    //Retornas el ViewModel.
    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Cierto... funcionó... gracias @JuanSalvadorPortugal